# jquery find descendant and click function

Tags: jquery, html, click, descendant

How do we call a specific function when clicking on a specific descendant - having specific attribute ?

I have html :

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How do I run something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form').find('input').click(function(){
        alert('');
    });

});
```

The function is to be called only when we submit.

Comment: Do you want to call the function at form submit!

Comment: yes, exactly, without changing the html.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can use the [:submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) selector to match only the submit button:

```
$('form input:submit').click(function() {
    alert('');
});
```

But in your case, it's probably better to handle the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event directly  on the form element:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert('');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the instant reply. Yes, that is what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code by:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(){
        alert('');
    };
});
```

Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it in javascript

```
<form  onsubmit="return foo();">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

script

```
function foo(){

return false;
}
```

using jQuery submit

```
$('form').submit(function() {

});
```